# Is there a more efficient way of writing a select list grouped by state in php

Tags: php, database, select, drop-down-menu

I am building a website and it has a select list grouped by state. Is there a more effective way of writing this select list, so I don't have a write so many different for loops?

I have a table in my database called location:

```
id    region            state
1     Sydney            NSW
2     Newcastle         NSW
3     Wollongong        NSW
4     Wagga Wagga       NSW
5     Geelong           Vic
```

...etc

Currently I am printing them out in a select list grouped by state like this.

```
<select name="location" id="location">
    <?php 
        $locations = getTable("location", $DB); 
        $locationsByState = [];
        //chunk array by state
        foreach($locations as $loc)
        {
            $locationsByState[$loc['state']][] = $loc;
        }
    ?>
    <optgroup label="NSW">
        <?php
            foreach($locationsByState['NSW'] as $opt)
            echo '<option>' . $opt['region'] .'</option>'
        ?>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="QLD">
        <?php
            foreach($locationsByState['QLD'] as $opt)
            echo '<option>' . $opt['region'] .'</option>'
        ?>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="SA">
        <?php
            foreach($locationsByState['SA'] as $opt)
            echo '<option>' . $opt['region'] .'</option>'
        ?>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="VIC">
        <?php
            foreach($locationsByState['VIC'] as $opt)
            echo '<option>' . $opt['region'] .'</option>'
        ?>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="TAS">
        <?php
            foreach($locationsByState['TAS'] as $opt)
            echo '<option>' . $opt['region'] .'</option>'
        ?>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="WA">
        <?php
            foreach($locationsByState['WA'] as $opt)
            echo '<option>' . $opt['region'] .'</option>'
        ?>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="ACT">
        <?php
            foreach($locationsByState['ACT'] as $opt)
            echo '<option>' . $opt['region'] .'</option>'
        ?>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="NT">
        <?php
            foreach($locationsByState['NT'] as $opt)
            echo '<option>' . $opt['region'] .'</option>'
        ?>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Why not use `foreach` inside `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cover that in 2 simple loops as below:

```php
<select name="location" id="location">

<?php 
    $locations = getTable("location", $DB); 
    $locationsByState = [];

    // chunk array by state
    foreach($locations as $loc)
    {
        $locationsByState[$loc['state']][] = $loc;
    }

    foreach($locationsByState as $label => $value) { 
?>

    <optgroup label="<?= $label; ?>">
        <?php
            foreach($value as $opt) {
                echo '<option>' . $opt['region'] .'</option>'
            }
        ?>
    </optgroup>

<?php 
    } 
?>

</select>
```